# Joins not by related field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

I have two models:
Question (id,text,section,factor)
Answer (id,question_id,selected)

Question has_many :answers
Answer belongs_to :question

My goal is to find factor of Question which *text* is equal to answer's *selected* field and I search only from answers

To show that I mean here is SQL that gives my expected result

```
SELECT questions.factor FROM answers INNER JOIN questions 
ON questions.text = answers.selected WHERE answers.id = 5
```

In rails I try to use joins

```
answers.joins(:question).where('questions.section = 4').where
('answers.selected = questions.text')
```

but results are not exact, as I can see in console rails includes connection by related field *"questions"."id" = "answers"."question_id"*

```
SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" INNER JOIN "questions" ON
"questions"."id" = "answers"."question_id" WHERE "answers"."participant_id" = $1 
AND (questions.section = 4) AND (answers.selected = questions.text)
```

Well, I believe that charm of Ruby should work here, please advice my some brilliant way to get wanted result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `answers.joins(:question)` will build always generate `INNER JOIN "questions" ON "questions"."id" = "answers"."question_id"` because that is how the `belongs_to :question` association is defined in `Answer`.

But you can just pass a string to `join` with the condition you need. Something like this (you might need an additional `where` for the `id = 5` condition):

```
answers.joins('INNER JOIN questions ON questions.text = answers.selected')
```

Comment: Wow. Never knew joins accepted the condition like that.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @spickermann is spot-on! And with full sincerity, please use it. However, with this question, I started playing with `Arel` on how to do the same and came up with:

```
custom_join = Answer.joins(:questions).on('questions.text = answers.selected').join_sources
# above will return an array with an inner join representation in Arel
Answer.joins(custom_join).where('questions.section = 4')
#=> ActiveRecord::Relation result
```